# stopping / pausing download programmatically using wget

Tags: shell, sh

I want write a shell script that downloads a file from server but after few seconds it shd stop. Please let me know how to avchieve this?

Regds

Comment: what shell are you using?

Comment: I am talking about sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the STOP and CONT [signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) to the wget subprocess, using the [`kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) command, like:

```
kill -STOP <pid>
kill -CONT <pid>
```